# Monitor not recognized after Nvidia (Cuda)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, display

I installed Nvidia drivers and CUDA drivers to run a GTX970 for mining ethereum (cryptocurrency) on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. Everything went well.

After removing the GPU a couple of weeks later and trying to run the monitor again on integrated graphics only, it doesn't work anymore! After turning the monitor on, it says "no connection" and goes to sleep.

The system is still accessible through ssh, so I think it must be some configuration problem or software mismatch that is now blocking the integrated graphics drivers somehow! Does anyone have suggestions? I'm not sure where to start debugging. Google was no help.